# Can I remove "that among" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

*In addition, poverty was more common among people with children compared to **that among** those who did not live with their kids.*

**That** here refers to **poverty** and I feel like I should compare **the poverty among one group** to **that among another**, but it sounds much neater to me without the "that among" part.

What is your advice here?

Comment: Only if you consider it to be elided, which is a dubious interpretation. Forget neatness here and focus on grammatical and semantic correctness.

Comment: Grammar issues aside, clarity is lacking.  What are you comparing, exactly?  Households where elderly parents are living with their grown children and households of elderly parents living apart from their grown children, and their poverty rates? Or households of young parents with children and households of elderly parents living apart from their grown children?

Comment: On the grammar of the comparison, " ... more common among X **than among** Y".  "compared to" is redundant; the idea is already expressed with "more common".

Comment: @TimR Regarding your first question, it's the former.

Comment: "parents with children" is not an idiomatic way to refer to households where elderly parents are living with their adult children.

Comment: @TimR As for the second comment, so you mean that I don't need to add "that", right? By your advice, the following sentence is also correct: The poverty rate among Indians is higher than among Americans. But it sounds a bit strange to me.

Comment: Thank you! I'll rephrase that "parents with children part".

Comment: I wouldn't use "poverty rate among" but "poverty rate in" in that specific instance.

Comment: In Ludwig.guru, poverty rate among a group of people is pretty commonly used.

Comment: Poverty is higher among households where elderly parents are living with their adult children than among households where elderly parents are living in their own homes.

Comment: I don't care what Ludwig guru says. You're comparing two different countries there, not ethnicities. Poverty rate in India vs poverty rate in America.

Comment: I would also use "The poverty rate in India", but here it's Indians. "The poverty rate in Indians" sounds really weird in my mother tongue. I know English is different. I just want to make sure that there's no misundersanding here.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting "in Indians" but "in India".  But there are times when you *can* use **in** with groups.

Comment: Oh I got what you mean now.

Comment: For example, in a medical article you could readily find "incidence of high  blood pressure **in** middle-aged men".   Sometimes **in** is synonymous with **among**.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. One more thing, when I said it sounds strange to me, I meant the fact that there's no "that" anymore. A teacher of mine advised me to include "that" in these kinds of situations. He would write: __The poverty rate in India is higher than that in America.__ I guess he has acquainted me with structuring my sentence this way. So, "that" is actually unnecessary in these situations?

Comment: Consider the difference in how you are starting these sentences, as the *comparands* are different:   Poverty in India is higher .... Poverty is higher in ...

Comment: The beer produced in Munich is tastier than **that** produced in St Louis.   Where **that** = "the beer"

Comment: The beer is tastier in Munich than in St Louis.

Comment: This is enlightening, Tim. Thanks a lot for your time. You're my favorite teacher in the forum now.

Comment: I've found that examples using beer always go over well.

Comment: Children? Then kids? "In addition, poverty was more common among people **with kids than without kids**."

Comment: @YosefBaskin Could you tell me when I should paraphrase a word? In IELTS writing, paraphrasing is a real deal. They actually give you a higher band score if you can show them that you can use a variety of words. Thanks to you, I realized that I sort of abused it in my sentence. So when should I paraphrase a word? In the next sentence at least?

Comment: I don't paraphrase for the sake of variety. If it's in the kitchen, we already know it's not in the garage. Keep using the word kitchen (not the food place). In the same sentence, why switch from children to kids?

Comment: Because they require us to do it. Maybe not in an unnecessary way like I did, but we're advised not to use the same word over and over again in one essay. For example, instead of only using "the percentage of...", I was advised to also use "the proportion of...". That's just one example.

Answer (score 3):

No, because then you'd be comparing poverty with people.

As written, it compares poverty with poverty.

The pronoun 'that' refers back to the metric of poverty which was previously mentioned.

Comment: The phrase, *compared to that among*, in the original sentence could also be replace with the much easer to read, *than to*.  *In addition, poverty was more common among people with children **than to** those who did not live with their kids.*

Comment: So we can use "to" in place of "among"? Could you please expand on it?

Comment: @EllieK do you mean "than among"?

Comment: @BenjaminGrange - Indeed I do.  Nice catch.